# Unable to install Enhanced Class Decompiler in RAD

Tags: rad, decompiler, wcs

I am trying to install Enhanced Class Decompiler plugin from marketplace in IBM Rational Application Developer Version: 9.5.0.2
. But getting below exception ,

```
Unable to read repository at https://ecd-plugin.github.io/update/content.xml.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:35)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:31)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.b(as.java:806)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:102)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.i(as.java:969)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:680)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.startHandshake(as.java:859)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Please help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

IBMs JRE does not like Githubs new SSL setup, so you can either try and fix it (the relevant part of the JRE is found in `%RAD_HOME%\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\security`)

or just get the latest ECD release from here:

https://github.com/ecd-plugin/ecd/releases

For version 3.0, download

https://github.com/ecd-plugin/ecd/releases/download/v3.0.0.201709092115/enhanced-class-decompiler-3.0.0.201709092115.zip

which contains a "features" and "plugins" folder. The contents of these need to go into the respective folders in your RAD installation, ie. `%RAD_HOME%\SDP`.

After starting RAD, it should be configured to use ECD for ".class" and ".class-without-source."